# I'm using Python 3.7 an BS4 for web scraping, there is a problem I couldn't solve, hope someone knows how to fix this

Tags: python, python-3.x

I suppose to get product information from [source page](https://list.jd.com/list.html?cat=9987,653,655&ev=exbrand_15127&page=1), the data I want is in the HTML tag , but there is another  tag in  tag, so when I save the data to local storage, it looks very bad. I hope someone knows how to fix this problem.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://list.jd.com/list.html? 
cat=9987,653,655&ev=exbrand_15127&page=1'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

filename = "params.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
#grabs each product
li_containers =  page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"gl-item"})
for i in range(0,len(li_containers)):
   p_name_div = li_containers[i].find("div",{"class":"p-name"})
   p_name = p_name_div.a.em.text.strip()
   print(p_name)
   f.write(p_name)
f.close()
```

There is the some screenshots.

I wanted it to be like this:

[image: I wanted it to be like that:]

But it ended up looking like this:

[image: But it looks like that:]

[Without span tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYffh.png)

[With span tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYYKf.png)

Comment: The data is in the em tag ,but there is another span tag in the em tag

Comment: Your post is incorrectly formatted. You  need one more new line after "there is my code"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
my_url = 'https://list.jd.com/list.html? 
cat=9987,653,655&ev=exbrand_15127&page=1'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

filename = "params.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
#grabs each product
li_containers =  page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"gl-item"})
for i in range(0,len(li_containers)):
   p_name_div = li_containers[i].find("div",{"class":"p-name"})
   p_name = p_name_div.a.em.text.strip()
   print(p_name.strip(" "))
   f.write(p_name.strip(" "))
f.close()
```